# Time configuration in PHP

Tags: php, timezone, wamp

We have a WAMP server running on America/New_York time and a Scheduled task that runs every day at 1.30AM local time or 5.30GMT (6.30 BST).

It ran this morning (8/4/14) but running "date('Y-m-d')" outputs '2014-04-07' even though the unix timestamp is 1396935011 (Tue, 08 Apr 2014 05:30:11 GMT).

What on earth am I missing? Why would it daily tell us it is run the day before even though I know that it definitely hasn't.

Thanks

A

Comment: What on earth is missing is your code.

Comment: @PeeHaa Code not necessary, it was a server config issue. Not strictly the correct site for this question I know but it was easier to answer it than complain about it. If you did the down vote would you mind undoing it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running a scheduled task, can I assume you mean you run a PHP CLI script from Task Scheduler?

If so you will also have to make the timezone change to the `\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.y\php.ini` file so that the CLI also knows that it is running in the New_York time zone.

```
date.timezone = "America/New_York"
```

Comment: I think thats it! Thanks.

Comment: No it wasn't. I can't upvote because I have no "reputation". Sorry :(

Comment: No problem, just thought you may have hit the wrong button. Are you allowed to make it a right answer?

Comment: It actually turns out I was running a script which is setting the timezone to America/Vancouver. Have no idea why but hoping that fixes it to.